# How to add a condition statement in geom_text for ggplot?

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-text

I have a plot that looks at 2 quarts worth of data. I also included a target value (dashed line) and a YTD section (which is the cumsum(count).

I am having an issue trying to show the # in that section added for YTD but only for 1 of the quarters (since Q1 should already have a value inside the bar plot). Currently it is showing 0 and 2 in the plot below but I only want to show everything > Q1 values.

### Current plot

[image]

I have tried with this current approach but does not seem to work:

```
  **geom_text(aes(label = ifelse((quarter_2022= "Q1"), total_attainment, ifelse(quarter_2022="Q2",total_attainment+2)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 1))) +**
```

### Plot Code

```
   ggplot(df1, aes(x=quarter_2022, y=total_attainment)) +
   geom_col(aes(y = YTD_TOTAL), fill = c("green1", "green2"), color = "black") +
   geom_text(aes(y = YTD_TOTAL, label = scales::percent(YTD_PERCENT_ATTAINMENT)),
             vjust = -0.5) +
   geom_col(fill = "gray70", color = "gray20") + 
   geom_text(aes(label = YTD_TOTAL - total_attainment),
             position = position_stack(vjust = 1.25))+
    geom_text(aes(label = total_attainment),
             position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
   geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(as.factor(quarter_2022)) - 0.4, 
                    xend = as.numeric(as.factor(quarter_2022)) + 0.4,
                    y = attainment_target, yend = attainment_target),
                linetype = "dashed") +
   geom_text(aes(label = attainment_target),
             position = position_stack(vjust = 4))
```

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(attainment_target = c(7.5, 15), quarter_2022 = c("Q1", 
"Q2"), year = structure(c(1640995200, 1640995200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), total_attainment = c(2, 4), percent_attainment_by_quarter = c(0.2666, 
0.2666), ytd = c(2, 6), YTD_TOTAL = c(2, 6), YTD_PERCENT_ATTAINMENT = c(0.266666666666667, 
0.4)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: You might want to customize the `data` argument to `geom_text`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a logical column in your dataset that indicates whether the label is 0. In the geom_text that creates the label, set the color aesthetic to the logical column. Use `scale_color_manual(values = c(NA, "black"), na.value = NA)` to assign no color to the labels that were 0s.